# How to convert Tensorflow Multi-head attention to PyTorch?

Tags: python, pytorch, tensorflow2.0, transformer-model, multihead-attention

I'm converting a Tensorflow transformer model to Pytorch equivalent.
In TF multi-head attention part of the code I have:
`att = layers.MultiHeadAttention(num_heads=6, key_dim=4)`
and the `input` shape is `[None, 136, 4]` where None is the batch size, 136 is sequence length and 4 is embedding dimension. `num_heads` is number of heads and `key_dim` is dimension of each head.
It gets the input as : `att(query=input, value=input)`

In pyTorch, the MHA is defined as `att = nn.MultiheadAttention(embed_dim, num_heads)` where `embed_dim` is the dimension of the model (Not dim of each head) and it must be divisible by `num_heads = 6`.
Since the input shape is `[None, 136, 4]` and 4 is not divisible by 6, Pytorch rises an error about divisibility. how should I change my input to be able to use Pytorch instead of TF?

If `key_dim` in Tf is 4 and it has 6 heads, the whole model's dimension must be 4*6. I defined `embed_dim` in PyTorch equal to 4*6 but because of input size of `[None, 136, 4]`, Pytorch rises error for dimension saying " expected input of size 24 but got 4".
Is it ok to repeat my input for `num_head` times to fix the problem?
Does TF feeds the input directly to each head without dividing it to number of heads?
How can I convert TF MHA to Pytorch MHA?

Comment: Here is the **opposite** (it may give some pointer).
https://gist.github.com/innat/e88b096390985e806299b4a3dccc5118

Comment: Seems Tensorflow let you directly feed same input to either each head or dimensionaly divide it into them but Pytorch doesn't have this option (or I couldn't figure it out). so I wrote my own MHA in Pytorch in the way TF designed it. However, thank you for responding.